# Can’t load stockEvents with amcharts eventDataLoader when calling MVC controller action

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, amcharts, amstock

I’m using amcharts stock chart. When using the following code, my chart loads fine and everything works:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "stock",
    "theme": "light",
    "dataSets": [{
        "title": "Values",
        "color": "#b0de09",
        "fieldMappings": [{
            "fromField": "value",
            "toField": "value"
        }, {
             "fromField": "average",
             "toField": "average"
        }],
        "dataProvider": @Html.Raw(ViewBag.ChartData),
        "categoryField": "date"
   }],
   ...
```

And my controller:

```
public class ChartController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.ChartData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GetChartData ());
        return View();
    }
}
```

However, when I try to add stock events by adding the following code, two things happen: 1) the chart no longer displays, and 2) the GetChartEvents action in the controller is never called, so obviously never returns any data.

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "stock",
    "theme": "light",
    "dataSets": [{
        "title": "Values",
        "color": "#b0de09",
        "fieldMappings": [{
            "fromField": "value",
            "toField": "value"
        }, {
             "fromField": "average",
             "toField": "average"
        }],
        "dataProvider": @Html.Raw(ViewBag.ChartData),
        "categoryField": "date",
        "eventDataLoader": {
            "url": @Url.Action("GetChartEvents", "ChartController"),
            "format": "json",
            "showCurtain": true,
            "showErrors": true,
            "async": true
        }
   }],
   ...
```

and in the controller

```
public class ChartController : Controller
{
    …
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetChartEvents()
    {
        ChartEvent[] events = new ChartEvent[3];
        events[0] = new ChartEvent(new DateTime(2007, 12, 17));
        events[1] = new ChartEvent(new DateTime(2008, 10, 27));
        events[2] = new ChartEvent(new DateTime(2009, 07, 06));

        return Json(events);
    }
}
```

ChartEvent is my own class, but because GetChartEvents is never called, I don’t think the issue is how the returned data is formatted.
In the view, if I replace

```
"url": @Url.Action("GetChartEvents", "ChartController"),
```

With

```
"url": "/Chart/GetChartEvents",
```

GetChartEvents is still never called, but the chart does display itself. I even tried placing the events in the ViewBag, but that doesn’t work either

```
"dataProvider": @Html.Raw(ViewBag.ChartData),
"stockEvents": @Html.Raw(ViewBag.ChartEvents)
```

As a final note (and sanity check!), if I output to the page the contents of @Html.Raw(ViewBag.ChartEvents), I get the following that appears fine:

> [{"date":"Date(2007,12,17)","type":"arrowUp","backgroundColor":"#00CC00","graph":"g1","description":" "},
>   {"date":"Date(2008,10,27)","type":"arrowUp","backgroundColor":"#00CC00","graph":"g1","description":" "},
>   {"date":"Date(2009,07,06)","type":"arrowUp","backgroundColor":"#00CC00","graph":"g1","description":" "}]

Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following their guide [here](http://www.amcharts.com/kbase/using-data-loader-plugin/), there are few things that might cause problem.

First, quotes:

```
"url": '@Url.Action("GetChartEvents", "ChartController")',
```

Notice single quotes around the URL. Without them your js is just invalid, and that's why the graph does not display.

Second, they use "dataLoader" and not "eventDataLoader" property.

Third, make sure to include dataloader plugin:

```
<script src="amcharts/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei
Indeed, I added the quotes, and yes I had forgotten to reference the plugin, which I added. However, eventDataLoader is correct, and is mentioned in the guide you referenced towards the bottom of the page. That being said, we’ re making progress because now I get an overlay on the chart saying
    Error loading the file: /ChartController/GetChartEvents
However the GetChartEvents method still never gets called.

Comment: I'm not a .net guy, but I recommend checking your logs and the browser console's network tab for the attempted request to /ChartController/GetChartEvents and see what that returned in the response.That will likely tell you what's going on.

Comment: After a few changes, I realised that the controller name was incorrect because mvc adds the word “controller” to the path, so I updated the call to 
    "url": '@Url.Action("GetChartEvents", "Chart")',
and the controller action is now being called. Thanks for everyones help.